# C algorithm for Matlab code wden (wavelet denoising)

Tags: c, matlab, wavelet, noise-reduction

Can anyone give me the source code in C for the following Matlab wavelet denoising method, I have to implement it on an ARM board so Matlab library wont work.

```
xd1 = wden(x,'sqtwolog','s','mln',5,'db5');
```

Where `xd1` is the denoised signal and `x` is my input signal.

I require it for denoising the breathing signal.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Basically, you are trying to reverse engineer a matlab function, and use it elsewhere outside matlab.

Comment: yes, if you could kindly help me please